# Share digital audio between computers

Tags: usb, audio, audio-adapters, audio-quality

So my situation is that I have two computers. One is my laptop that goes everywhere with me and is a sort of workhorse rig. The other is my gaming desktop rig.
I have one set of USB headphones that I use all the time.

What I'm wanting to do is take the audio out from my laptop and put it into my computer in 7.1. Up until now I have been using a 3.5mm male to male cable. It works but it creates noise and its a pain. I've looked into network based solutions but all have 1-2 seconds of lag and I would need almost 0 latency.

Is there some kind of dongle that can plug into my laptop and show as USB speakers and then plug into my desktop and show as USB input which I can then monitor on my headphones? Or any other solution to share digital audio between the two?

Note: neither computer has spdif but if anyone knows of a cheap spdif dongle that could also work.

Comment: Have you tried a different cable?  Noise on the line is usually caused by the cable itself being poorly made or poorly insulated.  A better quality cable may solve the problem.